# How can I setup multiple repositories for mvn builds?

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I want to download 'standard' jars like Spring framework from central maven repository, but proprietary license jars from our custom maven repository (Artifactory) repo. I've setup the pom.xml file this way:

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>maven2</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>   
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Artifactory</name>
        <url>https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

It's not working the way I want it.  Here is what I get now:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpreadSheetUploadWeb 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.10/jackson-databind-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.10/jackson-databind-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.10/jackson-databind-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.10/jackson-databind-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.10/jackson-databind-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/1.9.10/jackson-annotations-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/1.9.10/jackson-annotations-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/1.9.10/jackson-core-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/1.9.10/jackson-core-1.9.10.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc_license_cisuz/10.5.9/db2jcc_license_cisuz-10.5.9.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc_license_cisuz/10.5.9/db2jcc_license_cisuz-10.5.9.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.403 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-04T07:47:47-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpreadSheetUploadWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project SpreadSheetUploadWeb:SpreadSheetUploadWeb:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.10: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:1.9.10: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:pom:1.9.10 from/to 2 (https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual): Access denied to https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-ic2esprint-bluecost-libs-maven-virtual/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/1.9.10/jackson-databind-1.9.10.pom. Error code 401, Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Log file?

Answer (score 2):

The  tags do not affect the order at which maven uses repositories to fetch dependencies.

So the  for maven central should be central, just for good practice.

However, your order is right but your links are not correct. you did not specify the central repository correctly. Try this instead:

```
<repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>maven2</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

For your artifactory, try with your browser if you can connect to https://swg-devops.com/artifactory . Try also with https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and you should see how it should look like. When you have the correct link resolved you should be able to download the dependencies and maven automatically tries all the repositories from first to last to find the dependency.

Comment: I corrected my pom.xml entries - I used the browser as you suggested to navigate to the repos.   Our Artifactory has some spring jars but not spring-boot jars, I verified.   And those are jars that are missing in the error log above....

Comment: This worked as soon as I placed it in settings.xml file in my MVN_HOME/.m2 directory